# how can delete rows by slowly changing dimension in type 1?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to implement an ETL process for our Type 1 slowly changing dimension tables in a SQL 2014 database.

in slowly changing dimension there are "new output" and "changing attribute updates output", but how can handle deleted rows from source by slowly changing dimension?

Comment: Don't use the Slowly Changing Dimension component.  It is difficult to maintain, edit in the future and takes forever to run through your data.  Have a read through this: https://benefic.net/ssis-alternatives-to-the-scd-transform/